# Множественное наследование

Tags: javascript

Нерабочий код. Хочу чтобы объект унаследовал свойста от 2 конструкторов

```
function Parent(autor, joi) {
        this.name = autor
        this.fam = joi
    }

    function Parent2(autor2, joi2) {
        this.name2 = autor2
        this.fam2 = joi2
    }

Parent.prototype.say = function () {
    return this.name
}

function ala() {}
ala.prototype = new Parent('one', 1)
ala.prototype = new Parent2('two', 2)
obj = new ala()
alert(obj.name)
alert(obj.name2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот урок из простого курса JavaScript

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Прототипы и наследование</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Rectangle(h, w) {
            this.height = h;
            this.width = w;

            // prototype - содержит методы и другие свойства, которые должны совместно использоваться всеми объектами типа.
            Rectangle.prototype.area = function () { return this.height * this.width; };
        }

        var r1 = new Rectangle(10, 20);
        var r2 = new Rectangle(20, 4);

        var areaOfFirst = r1.area();
        var areaOfSecond = r2.area();

        document.write("Area 1 : " + areaOfFirst + "<br/>");
        document.write("Area 2 : " + areaOfSecond + "<br/>");

        // Метод меняется во всех объектах типа Rectangle.
        Rectangle.prototype.area = function () { return this.height + 1; }

        areaOfFirst = r1.area();
        areaOfSecond = r2.area();
        document.write("<br/><br/><br/>After changes <br/>");
        document.write("Area 1 : " + areaOfFirst + "<br/>");
        document.write("Area 2 : " + areaOfSecond + "<br/>");

        // Свойства прототипа наследуются всеми объектами.
        // Если производиться чтение свойства, которого нет в объекте но есть в прототипе, возвращается
        // значение из прототипа (в объект при этом свойство не добавляется)
        // Если попытаться записать значения для свойства которого нет в конкретном объекте, но есть 
        // в прототипе, JavaScript создаст это свойство в конкретном объекте и меняет свойство объекта. 
        // Прототип при этом остаётся со старым значением.
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Пасибо огромное